# Auto reply after clsoing time C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a texting App using C# and the Twilio API. I'm trying to make it have an auto reply when a customer texts after 6pm but I cant figure out how to do it I'm using DateTime to set the times for open and close but I cant figure out how to continue after that. Thank you in advance

```
namespace Mercury.Controllers
{
    class ClosingHoursController : SmsController
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime start = new DateTime(8, 0, 0);
        DateTime close = new DateTime(18, 0, 0);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be available in a single timezone, only?

Comment: those time you give there is new DateTime(year,month,day)

Comment: I want it to run by our timezone no matter where the texts are coming from

Comment: First, read the DateTime documentation. Running what you have will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: When you have `now` as a class-level field, then it gets initialized when the controller instance is created. It doesn't *stay* up-to-date. You may want to use `DateTime.Now` inside a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the message time is between your opening hours. A DateTime.Now initialised in a class will remain set at the time you initialised it so better to call a method as and when you require it.

```
public void ReceiveMessage(object smsMessage)
    {
        if (AutoReply(smsMessage))
        {
            //Send the office closed message
        }
        else
        {
            //Continue as normal
        }
    }

    public bool AutoReply(object smsMessage)
    {
        bool autoReply = true;
        DateTime msgTime = smsMessage.MessageTime; //This is when your message came in - i'm assuming it will be a DateTime
        TimeSpan openTime = new TimeSpan(08, 0, 0); //This is when your office opens - i have put 08:00
        TimeSpan closeTime = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0); //....and this is when it closes - i have put 17:00

        if (msgTime.TimeOfDay > openTime && msgTime.TimeOfDay < closeTime) autoReply = false; //Set to true if we're between opening hours

        return autoReply;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define today plus some hours like this:

```
        var sixAM = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6);
        var sixPM = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18);
```

Or just check the `Hour` property of the DateTime you want to check.

```
    bool IsWorkingHours(DateTime theDate)
    {
        return (theDate.Hour > 6 && theDate.Hour < 18);
    }
```